# How to achieve multi column layout with inline images

Tags: css, microsoft-metro

I am trying to achieve multi-column layout with inline images.

As shown in the image below:

```
===========   ============   ============   ============   ============   + + + + + +
===========   ============   ============   ============   ============   +         +
===========   ============   ============   ============   ============   + Image-3 +
===========   ============   ============   ============   ============   +         +
+ + + + + + + + + + + +  +   ============   + + + + + +    ============   +         +
+                        +   ============   +         +    ============   +         +
+        Image-1         +   ============   + Image-2 +    ============   + + + + + +
+ Spanned across columns +   ============   +         +    Empty space    ============
+                        +   ============   +         +     as Image-3    ============
+                        +   ============   +         +     cannot fit    ============
+ + + + + + + + + + + +  +   ============   + + + + + +        here       ============
```

I have to use this in a windows 8 app JavaScript/HTML based app (**so you can assume it is only for IE 10**).

I tried to use following CSS but it doesn't lay out images as expected.

```
column-fill: auto;
column-gap: 30px;
column-width: 270px;
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using any grid system or building your own grid system?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [CSS multi-column layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) supported by internet Explorer 10.

Comment: CSS multi-column layout will not work as we cannot specify exact number of columns to be spanned for CSS column-span property

Comment: You don't need to specify it -- you only need to use it if you have specific columns that you want to be more than one. If you have dynamic content, it'll keep adding columns as needed.

Comment: I am talking about image to span across 2 columns. There is no way to specify that a particular image should span across 2 columns. It will either span across all columns or none.

Answer (score 0):

did you look at the -ms-grid-* properties ? 
api doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453256.aspx
an example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972605.aspx

Comment: That will not help, as number of columns will depend on the content. It should be fluid. Secondly, image positioning and spanning is also depend on content so I cannot use ms-grid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .col1{ float:left; left:5%;}
  .col2{float:left; left:15%;} 
  .col3{float:left; left:35%;} 
  .col4{float:left; left:55%;}
  .col5{float:left; left:75%;} 
  .col6{float:left; left:95%;}
  div{ display:inline;width:150px; padding:3px; margin:6px; text-align:justify;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="col1">
   multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. <img src="images/apms_buttonbgr.PNG" width="300">
   </div>

     <div class="col2">
  multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. 
   </div>

     <div class="col3">
  multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images.
   </div>

     <div class="col4">
  multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images.<img src="images/apms_buttonbgr.PNG">
   </div>

     <div class="col5">
  multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. <img src="images/apms_buttonbgr1.PNG" border="1">
   </div>

     <div class="col6">
  <img src="images/apms_buttonbgr.PNG"> multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. 
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```